# How to force gradle to use a specific appcompat-v7 version?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my gradle file I have this

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
            ...
}
```

But then, running `gradle dependencies` I see something like this

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
```

What may indicates that it is automatically using `23.1.1`. This causes problems with libraries depending on `23.0.0`. I get errors like this

> error: cannot find symbol variable dialog_fixed_height_major
>
> error: cannot find symbol variable dialog_fixed_height_minor
>
> error: cannot find symbol variable dialog_fixed_width_major
>
> error: cannot find symbol variable dialog_fixed_width_minor
>
> error: cannot find symbol variable 
>   RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton_Overflow

This is because those symbols [were removed](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/support_api_diff/23.1.0/changes/android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.html) on version 23.1.0

How can I force gradle to build agains `23.0.0` so I make dependencies happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is Gradles conflict resolution strategy. Some dependency you have depends on the newer version of the library. If you scroll down in the output of `dependencies`, then you see which one.

The default resolution strategy of Gradle is to take the newest requested version. You can change it to fail the build instead which means you have to resolve all version conflicts manually. But if you have stuff that depends on the newer version, the question is whether it can work with the older version.

You can read more about conflict resolution in the [Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:version_conflicts).